# creating a new table whenever a new row is inserted. Then insert that row's id to the new table's id

Tags: postgresql

There is a table called student where data type of id is serial.

| id | name | age |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | kim | 20 |
| 2 | sophi | 21 |

Now, I want to create new table(id int,details text) each time I insert a new row. Then, the same id will store in new table's id as well. This will continue to happen whenever I insert any new row.

I have created a trigger function followed by this:

```
create or replace trigger problem
after insert on student
for each row execute procedure fun();
```

```
create or replace function fun()
returns trigger 
as 
$$
begin
if new.id>old.id then
create table now(id int, name text);
insert into now(id)
values(new.id)
;
end if;
return new;
end;
$$
language plpgsql;
```

Function creation is done. But the issue is, I can't create many tables with the same name, here which is named as 'now'. What can be done?

I want to create a new table every time I insert a new row and then new row's id must insert to the new table's id.

I'm new to postgreSQL, and stuck with this problem for a while.
All guidance is much appreciated!
Thanks!

Comment: I cannot think of a situation where the creation of a new table for each new row makes sense. This being said, you could name the tables dynamically, for example `now_1`, `now_2`, or, generally `now_<id>` with something like `create table format('now_%s', new.id)(id int, name text);` if you absolutely need all the new tables?

Comment: This sounds like an [X-Y Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377) - what is the underlying, real problem you are trying to solve with that approach?

Comment: 1) No you don't. You want to create a child table that uses a `Foreign Key` relationship to the `student` table and then insert  a new row for each student into that table linked by `student.id` = `child_tbl.id`. 2) An `INSERT` trigger function does have an `OLD` record to select from. Read the docs [plpgsql trigger](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-trigger.html). 3) Because  a) The lack of `OLD` per 2) and b) The fact that SQL data is unordered `if new.id>old.id ` will never work.